# Post authentication redirectPath not working if user already logged in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm just starting out after generating a fresh laravel app using `artisan`. By following instructions available in the official docs about [Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication), I've added forms for login and registration.

Since I want user to be redirected to the `/dashboard` route after authentication, I've added the following to my `AuthController`:

```
protected $this->redirectPath = '/dashboard';
protected $this->redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

Things seem for work as expected. After a successful login, user is taken to the `/dashboard`.

The problem happens when a user has already logged in (using the `/auth/login` route) and is again navigating to the `/auth/login` route through the browser's address bar. In such cases, laravel is redirecting the user back to `/home`, a route which of course, is not defined in my app. So, I get the following error displayed in the browser:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

in RouteCollection.php line 143
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 746
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 237
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
```

I would have expected the user to be taken directly to the `dashboard`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it is handled by built-in RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware, the interesting part is

```
if ($this->auth->check()) {
    return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
}
```

Comment: Oh. Yes, I noticed. I didn't realize it was part of the application code. I thought it was coming from the vendor code (which of course, I don't want to change). I thought I was missing something. So, it's as simple as putting a `RedirectResponse(url('/dashboard')` there?

Comment: yes, simply changing it will do
you can edit anything out of the vendor directory, some things need more care, but nothing will break with packages update if you do so (unless some incompatible version appears of course)

Answer (score 0):

The `RedirectsUsers` class is a trait so you cloud override the `redirectPath` method in your `AuthController`, to do so just copy the method and paste it in your `AuthController` making the modifications you need, something like this.

```
/**
 * Get the post register / login redirect path.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function redirectPath()
{
    return route('home');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

**explanation**: since in Laravel default redirect path is / , so I made use of this and created a route by applying it the middleware and added a condition/logic such that :

" if user is logged in , then redirect it to controller action."

```
   Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth', function (){ 

    if(Auth::check())
    {
        return redirect()->action('BrandController@index');
      //return redirect('/')
    }
    }]);
```

Hope this solve your problem.